# How do I set the highlighted title colour of a subclassed UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I've subclassed `UIButton` and am trying to set the title colour when the button is highlighted. The custom button is also on a nib file.

I have the code:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted]; // Offending line

}
```

However, the view does not load (seemingly goes into an infinite loop and doesn't show) when I have the `setTitleColor:forState:` line. Is it supposed to be declared elsewhere? How else do you set the highlighted title colour of a custom `UIButton`?

Comment: by "// Offnding line", what exactly do you mean?  is it reporting a compile-time message? or an error when you attempt to execute it?  if the later, do you think you have a UIButton (or your subclass of it), but perhaps the object is actually something else?

Comment: The offending line is what makes the view crash. It goes into what seems like an infinite loop, and doesn't load. I'll update my question with this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to do this in layoutSubviews, this will avoid the infinite loop you are currently creating:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if (self.state == UIControlStateHighlighted) {
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that this is called several times during a view controller's lifecycle so it is really not efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Are you doing anything else with the UIButton subclass? If all you want to do is change the text colour you can use standard UIButton functionality:

```
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forControlState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forControlState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Do this when setting up the button, it doesnt need to happen everytime layoutSubviews is called

Comment: The reason for the custom button class is because it's a bit of a hack. I needed a custom font f.or my button, which kept crashing xcode when I selected it in my nib, so I programmatically changed the font. That's another issue altogether